# Remove "How to" Section from TFS Web Interface

Tags: tfs

Is there a way to remove "How To" and "About" annoying sections from TFS Web Interface.

And thats the ..., I talking about:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, just click the close box to the right of the heading:

[image: Click the close box]

Comment: LOL, in chrome u cannot see that, but when u hover over it, it works, thx mate!

Comment: You can't see this button in Mozilla either